# how to store 2 spaces in xslt variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:variable name="asteriskSpaceSpaceAsterisk" select="'*  *'"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$asteriskSpaceSpaceAsterisk"/>

EXPECTED OUTPUT
*  *
ACTUAL OUTPUT
* *
```

Question 1) The above line stores only 1 space instead of 2. How do i store 2 spaces

Question 2)

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with($strippedString,'*  *')">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring($strippedString,5,string-length($strippedString))"/>
</xsl:when>
```

I am not getting a match even if the string starts with a sub-string that contains 2 spaces between asterisks. What do I have to do to get a match?

I am using xslt 1.0

Comment: You should only really ask one question at a time (although you might asking just the first question ends up answering the second anyway). And you need to give more detail in the first question too. The XSLT snippet does store 2 spaces, but it may be another process that is "normalizing" the spaces to 1. Possibly you are outputting as HTML? So, you really need to show a sample of your input and your expected output too, and how you are using the variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a text to be rendered by a browser, you can define your variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="asteriskSpaceSpaceAsterisk" select="'*&#160;&#160;*'"/>
```

This way the string contains 2 **unbreakable** spaces, which will not be "squashed"
to a single space by a browser.

Another remark: In `substring` function, the third argument gives the **length** of
the output string, not the "stop position".

But if you want to extract a substring from some point, up to the end,
just omit this parameter.